# Python script to test CEF3 embedded application using selenium/chromedriver - cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:4444

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium-embedded

The application is an **embedded CEF3** C# MS Windows app which has enabled remote debugger address. I followed the java example and I can control the appplication using a java prg. However we use Python as the main test automation language and I tried to implement the same code in Python but I get a "*cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:4444*".
What do I miss here:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = "D:/dev/desktop-automation/selenium/chromedriver.exe"
chromeOps = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOps.binary_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Path to application/Application.exe"
chromeOps.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:4444"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOps)

time.sleep(3)
browser.get("http://example.com")
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The missing bit was to set this value prior running the script:
set webdriver.chrome.driver="D:/dev/desktop-automation/selenium/chromedriver.exe"
It seems that the os.environ does not set this value for the running script.